# mq_receive getting stuck on assembly b $1 (spin here indefinitely)

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am using the cc3220s launchpad, ccs compiler, TI-RTOS and SimpleLink CC32xx SDK
5.20.00.06.

The message queue is used to communicate between two pthreads:

```
pthread_attr_init(&pAttrs);
            priParam.sched_priority = 1;
            int detachState = PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED;
            status = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&pAttrs, detachState);
            status |= pthread_attr_setschedparam(&pAttrs, &priParam);
            status |= pthread_attr_setstacksize(&pAttrs, 4096);

            status |= pthread_create(&spawn_thread, &pAttrs, thread0,
                                    NULL);
            status |= pthread_create(&spawn_thread, &pAttrs, thread1,
                                     NULL);
if (status != 0)
            {
                /* pthread_create() failed */
                while (1)
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
```

Here is the code relating to the message queue, its inside thread0:

```
mq_attr defaultMqueueAttr = { 0, 1, 1, 0 }; 

mqd_t mqDes0 = mq_open("messagequeue0", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666,
&defaultMqueueAttr);

char var0 = 0;

mq_receive(mqDes0 , (char\*) receive, 1 ,0);
```

once my code gets to mq_receive i do 'step in' to see whats actually happening and im taken to the function itself:

```
ssize_t mq_receive(mqd_t mqdes, char *msg_ptr, size_t msg_len,
        unsigned int *msg_prio)
{
    MQueueDesc *mqd = (MQueueDesc *)mqdes;
    MQueueObj  *msgQueue = mqd->msgQueue;
    UInt32      timeout;
    int         retVal = -1;

    /*
     *  If msg_len is less than the message size attribute of the message
     *  queue, return an error.
     */
    if (msg_len < (size_t)((msgQueue->attrs).mq_msgsize)) {
        errno = EMSGSIZE;
        return (-1);
    }

    if (mqd->flags & O_NONBLOCK) {
        timeout = BIOS_NO_WAIT;
    }
    else {
        timeout = BIOS_WAIT_FOREVER;
    }

    /* Receive a message */
    if (Mailbox_pend(msgQueue->mailbox, (Ptr)msg_ptr, timeout)) {
        retVal = (msgQueue->attrs).mq_msgsize;
    }
    else {
        errno = EAGAIN;
    }

    return (retVal);
}
```

The code executes all the way until if (msg_len < (size_t)((msgQueue->attrs).mq_msgsize)).
From here i thought normally itd either meet the if condition and return an error code, or not meet it and continue on. but once i click step into here my code jumps to an assembly file:

```
ti_sysbios_family_arm_m3_Hwi_excHandlerAsm__I:
        .asmfunc
        tst     lr, #4          ; context on PSP?
        ite     NE
        mrsne   r0, psp         ; if yes, then use PSP
        moveq   r0, sp          ; else use MSP

        mov     sp, r0          ; use this stack
        stmfd   sp!, {r4-r11}   ; save r4-r11 while we're at it
        mov     r0, sp          ; pass sp to exception handler
        mov     r1, lr          ; pass lr too
        mov     r4, lr          ; preserve LR in r4

        ldr     r2, excHandlerAddr
        blx     r2

        mov     r0, sp          ; for ROV
        mov     r1, r4          ; for ROV
$1
        b       $1              ; spin here indefinitely
```

Here the code executes all the way until 'b       $1              ; spin here indefinitely' and then it gets stuck.

ive tried changing multiple things like msg_len, the defaultMqueueAttr  etc. But nothing makes any difference.

Comment: Using _detached_ threads is usually problematic. I'd leave off the custom attributes for `pthread_create` until I got it working (e.g. 4096 is a _really_ small stacksize--ugh). Also, when you do `mq_open`, your attributes are: `{ .mq_maxmsg = 1, .mq_msgsize = 1 }` So, you're saying that the queue can only have _one_ message and messages can only be _one_ byte long? That might just be a bit too tight. Again, I'd pass `NULL` for the 4th arg to `mq_open` to use the system-wide default values. And, check the return value from `mq_open` for errors. The last arg to `mq_receive` is `1 0` (syntax???)

Comment: Im using detached threads because im making my threads inside another thread.(i shouldve mentioned in the post sorry)  and im not sure about the lifetime of the parent threads so i wanted to stay safe and completely sever the dependance. As for the message size and amount yes its just 1 byte long since i only need 1-127 and im only sending one value at a time.

Comment: This is all problematic and adding to the complexity. I've been doing `pthreads` coding for 20 years and haven't yet found the use case for a detached thread. Also, you're setting an explicit priority. And, [again], 4096 is too small for a stack. The default size is 8MB. You could be overflowing the stack with UB and corrupting the heap. The asm you're showing doesn't look like it could come from the posted C code. IMO, you're trying to do too much all at once. Simplify first, get it working, and add back later. You're not checking error returns on the function calls.

Comment: Your posted code won't even compile. We need your _real_ code. We would like an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we would like a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].